# Howcome when you find the resistance between A and B, you don't ignore the 2 Kohm resistor?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, resistance

Howcome when finding Vth, you ignore only the 2A current source, or make an open circuit between nodes A and B (ex: where the 1kOhm and 2kohm resistor and source respectively meet)?
[image]

Comment: @NirooshKa why should you? That's simply not what happens in that method. You could just as well ask why when you're looking for Rth, why you don't multiply all component values with 13.255299 and it would make about as much sense as your question!

Comment: @NirooshKa Let me explain with a (rather dumb) analogy. If you have a unknown machine that outputs coffee and chocolate at two different outputs, and you are only interested how much coffee it produces, then you only have to monitor the coffee output and you do not care what the chocolate output is. Same for your circuit: You are only interested the equivalent resistance Rth, so you may disregard the sources.

Answer (score 1):

When deriving Thevenin eq. Resistance, the current source is replaced by an infinite resistance. An infinite resistance means open circuit. Thats why it was "ignored".